# Problems with @emotion which is used only by react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

We use react-select 4.3.1 which uses @emotion for styles.
Unfortunately i get an error starting my react app:

TypeError: options is undefined
createCache
c:/dev/myapp/client/node_modules/@emotion/cache/dist/emotion-cache.browser.esm.js:178

```
  175 | var defaultStylisPlugins = [prefixer];
  176 | 
  177 | var createCache = function createCache(options) {
 178 |   var key = options.key;
  179 | 
  180 |   if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && !key) {
  181 |     throw new Error("You have to configure `key` for your cache. Please make sure it's unique (and not equal to 'css') as it's used for linking styles to your cache.\n" + "If multiple caches share the same key they might \"fight\" for each other's style elements.");
```

We do not use @emotion directly.
Any idea how to solve this?